# Cruzar varios ID's de un campo con una tabla

Tags: mysql

Saludos tengo el siguiente problema:

Nombre de mis tablas: 
Tabla_1 y Tabla_2

Nombre de mis campos:
En mi Tabla_1 tengo un Columna_X y en mi Tabla_2 tengo Columna_1 (ID) y Columna_2 (Detalle)

En la Columna_X de la Tabla_1 tengo almacenados datos de tipo string con valor numerico separado por ',' ej: 1,3,4,5,x,... son indefinidos el numero de registros

En la Columna_1 de la Tabla_2 tengo el ID (de tipo int) y la Columna_2 el Detalle en donde almaceno la etiqueta que tendria que aparecer al hacer el cruze o inner join.

Lo intente con un `INNER JOIN`, pero solo me trae un valor de uno ej:

```
SELECT

TD.Columna_2

FROM Tabla_1 T

INNER JOIN Tabla_2 TD ON T.Columna_X = TD.Columna_1
```

y el resultado solo es el primer Detalle no todos los detalles separados por comas como con los ID (numeros)

Comment: Hola @Rodrigo, si te he entendido bien el planteamiento de la tabla 1 es ilógico, ya que un campo que vas a usar para comparaciones debería tener un valor fácilmente comparable, y una concatenación de indefinidos elementos por comas no lo es. Si fuera un número de elementos manejable y definido se podría hacer con "substring_index" por ejemplo, pero en tu caso no va ser manejable. Si puedes variar el diseño de la base de datos plantea una tabla intermedia.

Answer (score 0):

Al igual que Carmen, creo que esta no es la mejor estructura para relacionar tablas, sin embargo, solo modificaría el inner join de tu consulta:

```
INNER JOIN Tabla_2 TD on cast(T.ColumnaX as nvarchar(max)) like '%,'+TD.Columna_1+',%'
```

solo me aseguraría de que el campo `Columna_X` comience y termine con una coma ","